# How to create a summary sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

PROBLEM
I have multiple tabs in a Google Spreadsheet and want to create a summary page where I can preview the content of each tab in a column on the Summary tab.
Each of the tabs have multiple items and they can be marked as "Approved" or "Rejected". I only want the "Approved" items to appear in the summary tab.

So, in the Summary sheet I want to return the content of **Column A** if **Column D** is "Approved".

I have been trying to use array functions like Sort or Index unsuccessfully.

Image examples below:

- [Summary sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SFaW.png)
- [Topic sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klAfc.png)

Comment: Use `FILTER()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FILTER()` formula which will spill result automatically and you no need to use arrayformula.

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!D:D="Approved")
```

[image]